# Restoration trainer dead at the college of winterhold. Where can I now buy higher level spells?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So the restoration trainer at the college of winterhold, [Colette Marence](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Colette_Marence), is gone. I don't think I killed her myself, but she's gone, and I have been trying to wait for her. I've already searched the college, and there is one bed in the hall of countenance that does't have the status "Owned".

Assuming that the character is dead, and [she apparently is the only one that teaches higher level restoration spells](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Restoration_Spells), where can I get them then?

Comment: Maybe it's just the bed and not the Restoration trainer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, I'm pretty sure she's not dead.

Unless you've already completed the Restoration Ritual Spell Quest (and gotten the two highest level spells from her), she should be flagged as Essential. That is to say, she should be unkillable. I know that I've been trying to for the past 10 minutes, and while she goes to her knees occasionally, she *JUST. WILL. NOT. DIE.*

So, what this means is one of two things. Either you've been hit by yet another famous Elder Scrolls Bug, and she's fallen through the world or otherwise despawned. While this is not *impossible*, I'd characterize it as pretty unlikely.

More likely, is the fact that she, and all the other college mages, wander around pretty constantly, and don't really keep to a 'schedule' the way most NPC's do. I once went weeks in game without being able to track down the Illusion trainer, for example. There are two unowned beds in the Tower of Countenance. They don't belong to anyone. It's not the bed that used to be Collete's.

As to where else you can get high level Restoration Spells, you'll find them randomly as leveled loot as you adventure -  especially in Necromancer and Vampire lairs -  though you'll never be able to gain access to the final two spells without completing the Ritual Spell quest, for which Collette is required.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! I'll arm myself with patience then! Hopefully she will show up, but i haven't seen her since i completed the "Eye of magnus" mission.

Comment: If you're playing on the PC, you can try using the console to teleport yourself to her, or disable/enable to see if that gets her to show up.

Comment: Those NPC mages are indeed annoying. The way I get them is to look for them roughly at the only time I know where they are : when they sleep. If they had a more consistent schedule they wouldn't need to have their sleep constantly interrupted by adventurers looking to buy spells.

Answer (score 4):

Colette Marence FOUND: I had this problem too so i though back to the last time i saw her which was on the bridge in the Eye of Magnus. So after a bit of exploring under the bridge with detect life i found her blue aura stuck trying to walk back to the college but stuck between a set of large rocks. It seems that when she is trying to get past the protective ward she can actually run off the bridge if you don't get it down fast enough.

If this is the case she can be freed by using unrelenting force, by pushing her far enough towards the town(not the college) she will eventually pick up the path back to normal life.

Granted this may not be the answer for every instance but it was mine and i was able to finish the quests for restoration. I hope it helps.